# How to skip pbr version check in Python packages

Tags: python, read-the-docs, python-pbr

I use pbr in my package. I also use readthedocs to host and generate the docs of the package.

pbr doesn't seem to have a way to skip the version checking when you add changes for the sake of configuration setting, e.g. if I add a yaml file for readthedocs, if I don't have a tag on that commit and have a version specified in my `setup.cfg` file which is the same as the previous version I had released - it complains that the target version should have been a patch higher. e.g I have `230.1.2` in `setup.cfg` and it expects `230.1.3`.

I don't want to bump the version each time I'm making a change to a configuration file, what can I do to avoid this?